# Learn Phonetics

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

As a non-native English speaker, I often search for the meaning of words on Google Search. Google provides the word's pronunciation in a written format. I do not understand how that written format is interpreted or used. What is the standard, standards body or authoritative reference for it?

I did try to figure out this out before asking here. The best result I got was **[this website](http://www.learnenglish.de/pronunciation/phoneticpage.html)**. It gives more examples but doesn't answer my question. What resources, websites only please, should I refer to?

The website must have phonetics in audible format as well as written format.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for, in the general case, is a guide to the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA).

Comment: I couldn't even figure out this is what I was looking for? Feeling dumb. But thanks :) Answer it I will mark it.

Comment: You're not dumb—just new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for, in the general case, is a guide to the International Pronunciation Alphabet (IPA).

- [Multilingual pronunciation key](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:IPA_pronunciation_key)
- [Live pronunciation tool](http://web.mit.edu/6.mitx/www/24.900%20IPA/IPAapp.html#)

Comment: Hey, are you home yet? :)

Comment: Still going home?

Comment: @Vahid oh man. Well we're all still going home in some respect, no? ;-) I'll put this on my todo for today.

Comment: @SeanAllred, sure ;-) , take ur time.

Comment: @Vahid see update; couldn't find much better than wiktionary, but i did find one site that played each sound on-demand.